# name for products of the form $\prod_i (1 + a_i t^i)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology, generating-functions

In the context of generating functions, is there an established name for (infinite) products of the form $\prod_i (1+a_it^i)$, or perhaps more generally $\prod_i (1+f_i(t))$, assuming that the valuation of $f_i(t)$ is increasing with $i$?

Comment: As an example, if $f(z)=g(z)\cdot f(p(z))$ and $g(1)=1$, then $f(z)=g(z)g(p(z))g(p^2(z))\dots$ which is of this form whenever $g(0)=g'(0)=0.$ One also has an infinite product for solutions $f$ to the functional equation $f(z)=g(z)f(p_1(z))\dots f(p_r(z))$.

Comment: Such infinite product expansions were introduced by J. F. Ritt, Math. Zeit. 32 (1930), 1-3. See also MR0045203.

Answer (score 2):

If $A(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots$ is an ordinary generating function for the species $A$, then the product defined above is the generating function for sets of objects of $A$, such that the objects in a set have pairwise distinct size (i.e. number of atoms). I'm not sure such structure is of significant interest?

Note that the similar product of the form $\prod (1+t^i)^{a_i}$ is known as $\operatorname{PSET}$ operator (see e.g. [here](http://jaypantone.com/courses/winter16math118/lecture-notes/lecture-notes-06.pdf)) and produces the generating functions for the sets of distinct objects of class $A$. It can be more recognizable in the form

$$
\operatorname{PSET} A(x) = \exp\left(A(x) - \frac{A(x^2)}{2} + \frac{A(x^3)}{3} - \dots\right)
$$